# gluLookAt() not working when using glOrtho()?

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw, glu

I want to use `gluLookAt()` to move my camera so that I can see the entire mesh (in the code is a cube).

I set `ModelView` matrix in the game loop. Both changing `glLookAt()` and `gluPerspective()` do nothing to the final image. I kept getting the below image.

I've tried to use `glOrtho()` but it was still not working...

Is this problem from shader, or the rest of the drawing code?

[image]

```
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <OpenGL/gl.h>
#include <OpenGL/glu.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int window_width = 800, window_height = 600;

GLuint loadShader(const char *vs_path, const char *fs_path);
const char *vertexShaderSource = "#version 330 core\n"
                                 "layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;\n"
                                 "void main()\n"
                                 "{\n"
                                 "   gl_Position = vec4(aPos.x, aPos.y, aPos.z, 1.0);\n"
                                 "}\0";
const char *fragmentShaderSource = "#version 330 core\n"
                                   "out vec4 FragColor;\n"
                                   "void main()\n"
                                   "{\n"
                                   "   FragColor = vec4(1.0f, 0.5f, 0.2f, 1.0f);\n"
                                   "}\n\0";

int main() {
    if (!glfwInit())
        return -1;
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);
    GLFWwindow* window;
    window = glfwCreateWindow(window_width, window_height, "Hello World", NULL, NULL);
    if (!window) {
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    int vertexShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(vertexShader, 1, &vertexShaderSource, NULL);
    glCompileShader(vertexShader);
    // check for shader compile errors
    int success;
    char infoLog[512];
    glGetShaderiv(vertexShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
    if (!success) {
        glGetShaderInfoLog(vertexShader, 512, NULL, infoLog);
        std::cout << "ERROR::SHADER::VERTEX::COMPILATION_FAILED\n" << infoLog << std::endl;
    }
    // fragment shader
    int fragmentShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(fragmentShader, 1, &fragmentShaderSource, NULL);
    glCompileShader(fragmentShader);
    // check for shader compile errors
    glGetShaderiv(fragmentShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
    if (!success)
    {
        glGetShaderInfoLog(fragmentShader, 512, NULL, infoLog);
        std::cout << "ERROR::SHADER::FRAGMENT::COMPILATION_FAILED\n" << infoLog << std::endl;
    }
    // link shaders
    int shaderProgram = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);
    glLinkProgram(shaderProgram);
    // check for linking errors
    glGetProgramiv(shaderProgram, GL_LINK_STATUS, &success);
    if (!success) {
        glGetProgramInfoLog(shaderProgram, 512, NULL, infoLog);
        std::cout << "ERROR::SHADER::PROGRAM::LINKING_FAILED\n" << infoLog << std::endl;
    }
    glDeleteShader(vertexShader);
    glDeleteShader(fragmentShader);

    float vertices[] = {
            -1, 0.0,  0.0,
            -1, 0.0,  1.0,
            -1,  1.0,  0.0,
            -1,  1.0,  1.0,
            1.0,  0.0,  0.0,
            1.0,  0.0,  1.0,
            1.0,  1.0,  0.0,
            1.0,  1.0,  1.0,
    };
    unsigned int indices[] = {
            0, 6, 4,
            0, 2, 6,
            0, 3, 2,
            0, 1, 3,
            2, 7, 6,
            2, 3, 7,
            4, 6, 7,
            4, 7, 5,
            0, 4, 5,
            0, 5, 1,
            1, 5, 7,
            1, 7, 3,
    };

    unsigned int VBO, VAO, EBO;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
    glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
    glGenBuffers(1, &EBO);
    glBindVertexArray(VAO);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, EBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(indices), indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof(float), (void*)0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    glBindVertexArray(0);

    glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE);

    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
        glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
        glLoadIdentity();
        gluLookAt(
                0, 0, 10,
                0, 0, 0,
                0, 1, 0);
        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
        glLoadIdentity();
        glOrtho(-10, 10, -10, 10, 0.1, 10);
        glViewport(0, 0, window_width, window_height);

        glUseProgram(shaderProgram);
        glBindVertexArray(VAO); // seeing as we only have a single VAO there's no need to bind it every time, but we'll do so to keep things a bit more organized
        //glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
        // glBindVertexArray(0); // no need to unbind it every time

        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }


    glfwDestroyWindow(window);
    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;

}

GLuint loadShader(const char *vs_path, const char *fs_path) {
    GLuint vertexShaderID = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    GLuint fragmentShaderID = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);

    std::string vsCode;
    std::ifstream vsStream(vs_path, std::ios::in);
    if (vsStream.is_open()) {
        std::string line;
        while (std::getline(vsStream, line)) {
            vsCode += line + "\n";
        }
        vsStream.close();
    } else {
        std::cerr << "ERROR::GUI::LOAD_SHADER::VERTEX::FILE_OPEN_FAILED\n" << std::endl;
        exit(-1);
    }

    std::string fsCode;
    std::ifstream fsStream(fs_path, std::ios::in);
    if (fsStream.is_open()) {
        std::string line;
        while (std::getline(fsStream, line)) {
            fsCode += line + "\n";
        }
        fsStream.close();
    } else {
        std::cerr << "ERROR::GUI::LOAD_SHADER::FRAGMENT::FILE_OPEN_FAILED\n" << std::endl;
        exit(-1);
    }

    int success;
    char info[1024];

    const char *vs = vsCode.c_str();
    glShaderSource(vertexShaderID, 1, &vs, NULL);
    glCompileShader(vertexShaderID);
    glGetShaderiv(vertexShaderID, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
    if (!success) {
        glGetShaderInfoLog(vertexShaderID, 1024, NULL, info);
        std::cerr << "ERROR::GUI::LOAD_SHADER::VERTEX::COMPILATION_FAILED\n" << info << std::endl;
    }

    const char *fs = fsCode.c_str();
    glShaderSource(fragmentShaderID, 1, &fs, NULL);
    glCompileShader(fragmentShaderID);
    glGetShaderiv(fragmentShaderID, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
    if (!success) {
        glGetShaderInfoLog(fragmentShaderID, 1024, NULL, info);
        std::cerr << "ERROR::GUI::LOAD_SHADER::FRAGMENT::COMPILATION_FAILED\n" << info << std::endl;
    }

    GLuint programID = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(programID, vertexShaderID);
    glAttachShader(programID, fragmentShaderID);

    glLinkProgram(programID);
    glGetProgramiv(programID, GL_LINK_STATUS, &success);
    if (!success) {
        glGetProgramInfoLog(programID, 1024, NULL, info);
        std::cerr << "ERROR::GUI::LOAD_SHADER::PROGRAM::LINKING_FAILED\n" << info << std::endl;
    }

    glDetachShader(programID, vertexShaderID);
    glDetachShader(programID, fragmentShaderID);
    glDeleteShader(vertexShaderID);
    glDeleteShader(fragmentShaderID);
}
```

Comment: IIRC `gluLookAt`-like functions only effect fixed pipeline rendering. maybe you should use something like `glm`

Comment: @appleapple Thanks for the comment. Does that mean if I use vertex buffer object, then gluLookAt will not be working?

Comment: more accurately, you cannot use these function (you can still call it, it just would't work) if you write your own shader.

Comment: First you need to decide if you want an orthographic projection or a perspective projection. They aren't interchangeable.

Comment: @user1118321 Hi, thanks for the suggestion. I'm sorry for the confusing description. I firstly use orthographic projection, but I just tried to use perspective projection for debugging. So if I want to do orthographic projection, do you know what's wrong with my code?

Comment: @appleapple Just a quick question. Did you mean to use `glm` in shader or outside of the shader?

Comment: Yes, I think apple apple was correct - you need to calculate the matrixes manually (probably using `glm`) and then pass that as a uniform to your vertex shader, where you need to multiply each vertex coordinate by the modelview and projection matrixes.

Comment: @AccM outside shader, I think you cannot use it inside :)

Comment: @AccM and inside shader there are build-in matrix operations. you can write something like `gl_Position = projection*modelview*vec4(aPos,1.0)` where `projection` and `modelview` are usually `unifrom mat4`

Comment: @appleapple So if I do it outside the shader, I still use `glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)`? It's just `gluLookAt()` doesn't work? What about `glOrtho()` and `glPerspective`? They are OpenGL functions, not `glu` functions. Are they effective?

Comment: @AccM when you bind your own shader to the pipeline, the fixed function pipeline is no longer available, and so calls that modify the fixed function pipeline like glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW) will not work. If no shader is bound to the pipeline those calls can still work, provided OpenGL is in compatibility mode which is what gives you access to legacy/deprecated OpenGL functionality

Comment: @AdaRaider Hi. I'm still not yet familiar with how OpenGL evolves. So if I use vertex buffer object (VBO) and vertex attribute array (VAO), together with element array buffer (EBO), can I still use the fixed pipeline? (like use `glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)`? I tried but nothing shows on the screen, so I'm curious..)

Comment: @AdaRaider Meanwhile, I found that built-in uniforms like `gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix` in shader are also deprecated. So I guess the "standard", or "modern" way of using OpenGL to draw, is to compute every transformation matrix outside of the shader, and then set them as `uniforms`, and use them as "model/view/projection" matrix?

Comment: @AccM as far as I know vertex buffers and VAO's are compatible with the fixed function pipeline you should be able to render with no problems. That part of modern OpenGL is compatible with the the fixed function pipeline. Uniforms are standard way of passing information to a shader, most people upload the MVP as one uniform but there's nothing stopping you uploading the three matrices with separate uniforms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fixed function matrix stack is deprecated. See [Fixed Function Pipeline](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Fixed_Function_Pipeline) and [Legacy OpenGL](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Legacy_OpenGL).

When you use a core profile

> ```
> glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
> ```

then you can't use the fixed function matrix stack.

Use [Uniform](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Uniform_(GLSL)) variables. Create a shader program with a projection matrix uniform (`u_proj`) and a view matrix uniform (`u_view`):

```c
#version 330 core

layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;

uniform mat4 u_proj;
uniform mat4 u_view;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = u_proj * u_view * vec4(aPos.xyz, 1.0);
}
```

Get the locations of the uniform variables after the shader progrma was linked:

```cpp
 glLinkProgram(shaderProgram);

 GLint projLoc = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "u_proj");
 GLint viewLoc = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "u_view");
```

Use a library like [OpenGL Mathematics (GLM)](https://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.9/index.html), to initialize the projection matrix and view matrix:

```cpp
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/type_ptr.hpp>
```

```cpp
glm::mat4 proj = glm::ortho(-10.0f, 10.0f, -10.0f, 10.0f, -10.0f, 10.0f);
glm::mat4 view = glm::lookAt(glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 5.0f), glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f), glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));
```

Set the values of the uniform variables after the program was installed:

```
glUseProgram(shaderProgram);

glUniformMatrix4fv(projLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(proj));
glUniformMatrix4fv(viewLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(view));
```

Comment: Thanks! That works perfectly! But could you explain why I commented out the core profile line of code, the entire program crashed? Does that mean I cannot do without core profile, i.e. fixed pipeline? (I'm using OS X)

Comment: @AccM I think you have to use core profile on OS X, but I'm not completely sure about that. Anyway, if you want to use OpenGL in a moder way, than you should use a core profile context.

Comment: @Rabbid76: You are correct: In macOS it's either use the core profile, or fall back to waaay old OpenGL.